# @oclif/test with `inquirer.prompt`

Tags: command-line-interface, prompt, inquirer, oclif

I am trying to test my entire cli dialogs using `oclif` and `@oclif/test`.
Prompts are made with `inquirer`.

Everything work fine, except the use of the `.stdin(` mock.

Feature extract looks like this:

```
...
const { sessionToken } = await inquirer.prompt([{
    type: 'password',
    name: 'sessionToken',
    message: 'Paste your token:',
    validate: token => 'Invalid token.',
}]);
...
```

Test code is:

```
  describe('with an invalid token', () => {
    fancy
      .stdout({ print: true })
      .command(['login', '-e', 'some@mail.com'])
      .stdin("bad_token")
      .it('should display invalid token', ctx => {
        process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
        process.stdin.once('data', data => {
          expect(data).toEquals("bad_token");
          expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('Invalid token.');
        });
      });
  });
```

**Actual**: The test stop on "Paste your token:"

**Expected**: The test continues and displays "Invalid token.", like when manually testing.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue, did you ever managed to overcome it?

Comment: No, I drop @oclif/test and I've created my on small test lib.

Comment: Would be interested in sharing it? I'm having trouble implementing this type of test and would be grateful for some inspiration.